# empty string prints None

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am running Django 1.9

I have RAW SQL query. My issue is with the empty strings.

When I print the empty strings in the template I am getting NONE. 
I know that I can use `{{ smt|default_if_none:""}}` but for me will be more comfortable if this is resolved in the view

When I use `Model.objects.filter()`  to do the query I don't have this issue.

What is the difference between the RAW queries and DJANGO ? 
How can I solve it without using filter tag

Thank you

Comment: If `smt` is empty string it will be rendered as empty string. Not None. Check your code.

Comment: Can you please add an example of how you are getting and using RAW SQL query data?

Comment: I solve my problem changing the Model for the strings I added default="" instead of null=True